# What's best to learn MySQLi or PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I literally just started to touch `MySQLi` from the old deprecated `MySQL` and I've been told recently that I should learn `PDO` over `MySQLi`. I'm not sure what to do! Someone help me out!

After a long time searching online for answers, I'd love to see and understand what's best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible duplicate! But heres my quick response.

As of the recent PHP update, `7.0`, the old `MySQL` function was removed from PHP. This does mean that most people will need to migrate to the newest two functions: `MySQLi` and `PDO`. I will give points on both functions and will also give my personal thoughts at the end.

## MySQLi

MySQLi is essentially an improvement of the now deprecated `mysql_*` function of PHP; however, this new function now supports prepared statements.

## PDO

PHP Data Objects, also known as PDO, is a general database abstraction layer which supports MySQL as well as many other databases. It supports prepared statements as well.

## What are prepared statements?

 
It is considered good programming practice to use Prepared Statements as they are very resilient against SQL injections/attacks. These SQL injection vulnerabilities occur due to the user input directly being made a part of the SQL query without properly sanitising it.

Personally, I make use of PDO due to it’s nature. But any of the two functions stated above are preferred as they support prepared statements.

Comment: I think ill probabley use PDO, from what I've heard it works best! Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I think it's the way to go! Best to learn it early then having to start learning multiple different MySQL functions.

Comment: The answer has no direct or indirect answer to the question of OP. It only explains what is MySQLi and PDO. (OP is asking which one is better).

Comment: @TareqMahmood You're right; however, I gave reasons why they are both preferred methods as questions involving the different functions are essentially personal preference. I will try and edit my answer to incline more toward the PDO pathway as it's what I use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest PDO. The biggest reason is, **PDO supports multiple databases**. But why should you think about multiple databases, if you are learning only mysql now? Here may be the reasons :

1. You may want to learn mysql now, but later you can also be interested in other databases. For example you decided to use oracle db for one of your future projects or any client project. Then you need to learn to use oracle specific functions like `oci_connect()`, `oci_execute()` etc. But if you have learnt PDO first, you don't need to learn any new PHP functions to implement it.
2. There may be cases when you need to change your database for better performance / security or any other purpose which may be required for your project. If you are in PDO, you will only need to update the few lines of SQL, which may differ between the two languages (that's not a lot). But if you have `mysqli_*` functions, you will need to update every single PHP functions you used for database purposes.

So, I would only suggest you to learn `mysqli`, if you are sure that you are not going to use any other database except mysql in your future life.